# Cannot find downloaded file(mp4)

Tags: youtube-dl

I have downloaded a video file from youtube via command line (youtube-dl) but couln't find it and when I again tried to download the same file the terminal says the file is already downloaded but after rigorous searching of the file in every folder I was unsuccessful.I have only one partition. My O.S is Ubuntu13.10.

Comment: on the same terminal run `pwd` command.The output shows some directory path. Your youtube file would be downloaded on that directory itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `find` command to search for it, if you'd like.

```
find ~/ -type f -iname 'somename'
```

Search for all files (`-type f`) in the `~/` (home) directory with name (case insensitive) `somename`. You can also use `-iname '*.flv'` if you know what the file extension is (in this case, `.flv`).

Comment: Nope. couldn't find it.

Comment: Assuming your `find` statement was correct, that actually means the video doesn't exist anywhere in your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

By default the videos should be downloaded into the current working directory.

If you're not sure where you are, just run `nautilus .` from the command line where you are and that should open up a file browser. Or you can run `pwd` to get the path.

There's quite a good recent answer pointing out [how to change the default location for `youtube-dl`](https://askubuntu.com/a/469400/449) which might help you in the future.

Comment: And don't forget the `.` after nautilus in `nautilus .` otherwise it will open up your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the [instruction](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/documentation.html):

```
Example: youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foobar". The video will be saved
to the file foobar.flv in that example. As YouTube.com videos are usually in Flash 
Video format, their extension should be flv.
```

The name depends from your link, the path should be the current (`pwd` show whichis)

Answer (score -1):

check in your home directory for the downloaded file